# 'Cannot get' error in node js with PUG

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Project Dir:
app.js

/Routes

/views

error: I am using express router for routing to /routes/search.js page but I am getting the cannot get problem with 404 not found error. I have done everything correct from routing to implementing view engine but still getting the error, when I am doing this on home DIR there is no problem but inside routes/ this is happening. please look at the pug file get action.

```
 app.js
var path=require('path');
var search = require('/routes/search');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'/views'));
app.set('view engine','pug');

app.use('/search', search);
```

/routes/search.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.end('searched');
});

module.exports = router;
```

/views/search.pug

```
form(action='../routes/search', method='GET')
    p SEARCH PAGE
    input(type='text', name='serchI', value='')
    input(type='submit', value='Submit')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send your search request to the route you've configured for search ( which here is `/search` ) **Not** the file itself:

```
form(action='/search', method='GET')
    p SEARCH PAGE
    input(type='text', name='serchI', value='')
    input(type='submit', value='Submit')
```

Now if you click *Submit* button a `get` request will send to `http://www.yourdomain.com/search` and it respond with `searched` text, because you've configured it to respond this way.

Read more: [express.Router](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router)

Comment: OMG, I didn't see that mistake. Thanks very much.